# is reading wordpress errors a good idea?

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently run a lamp stack with wordpress, and I don't believe the wordpress errors go into my apache logs.

I could modify wp-config to read the wordpress errors somewhere, but was wondering if it's worth the trouble if all the functionality works out.

Similarly, I have a lot of try and catch areas for php pdo database functions, and the functionality works out completely, was wondering if I should bother actually reading the errors there. Is that a security hazard, or is it something most people don't bother with.

Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to enable error in your live server then it's really not a good idea, But yes you can enable all the errors in your development environment and try to fix them as required.

Comment: okay thank you harish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't feel safe running my site if it regularly produces real errors. If you make it a habit to ignore the errors, you won't catch those that will bite you. Turn display_errors off for production, but don't hide the errors from your logs.

Most logged errors are easy to fix. If I find that a plugin does produce a lot of errors, I overthink using that plugin and keep my eye open for alternatives. After all, if the developer didn't invest the time and effort to get the basic right, how much do you trust the security of that plugin?

That said, I wouldn't read the error logs from start to finish on a busy site, but use scripts to filter out what I don't want to see because I already know about it but can't fix it. This means the usual 404s by buggy clients, exploit scanners, google hitting old content again and again etc, continuing the thought that if you train yourself to skip records, you will eventually skip records that you didn't want to skip.

Comment: okay thanks yeah it's not currently in production just yet, so i have an opportunity to fix it but i wonder if it's worth the hassle but in hindsight it probably is worth it. programming is sort of tough when doing it correctly so many things you gotta watch out for versus just making something and not planning for all the things that could go wrong - thanks

Comment: It is, but it's worth taking care of potential problems now instead of dealing with the fallout later if something blows up. You don't want to be the one to explain to your boss/customers/friends/fans why your software exposed their private data to malicious third parties.

Comment: thanks yeah i'm going to take your advice. I have coded for a lot of contingencies but reading the logs even if everything works perfectly is something i should have on my check list thanks.